# Derivation of the Stable Distribution

Tags: probability-theory

I have been trying to find A. N. Kolmogorov's and Levy's original derivations for the [stable distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution). However, I have been unable to locate them, or they are only in Russian or French, respectively, not obtainable, or later [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201024209) references are obscenely expensive. I would expect this derivation to exist somewhere readily available but I suppose not.

Does anyone have an idea where I can get a copy or where there is a source that is not so ridiculiusly expensive?

I appreciate the assist!

Comment: Is this useful?...Notice the "or" statement

Comment: I have edited the text to be absolutely and explicitely clear that the Russian wrote in Russian and the Frenchman wrote in French. There should be no further confusion.

Comment: A first track from Bibliothèque Nationale de France : https://data.bnf.fr/fr/12157691/paul_levy/